# How to filter JSON using jq stream

Tags: json, jq

I have a very large JSON file and the sample data looks like as:

```
{"userActivities":{"L3ATRosRdbDgSmX75Z":{"deviceId":"60ee32c2fae8dcf0","dow":"Friday","localDate":"2018-01-19"},"L3ATSFGrpAYRkIIKqrh":{"deviceId":"60ee32c2fae8dcf0","dow":"Friday","localDate":"2018-01-20"}}}
```

I need to put a filter on "localDate" field in jq stream such that the output looks like the following JSON as:

```
{"L3ATSFGrpAYRkIIKqrh":{"deviceId":"60ee32c2fae8dcf0","dow":"Friday","localDate":"2018-01-19"}}
```

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to retain the key-value pair while making a selection based on the values is to use `with_entries`:

```
jq '.userActivities
| with_entries(select(.value.localDate=="2018-01-20"))' input.json
```

## Output

```
{
  "L3ATSFGrpAYRkIIKqrh": {
    "deviceId": "60ee32c2fae8dcf0",
    "dow": "Friday",
    "localDate": "2018-01-20"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am working on a very large JSON of around 20 GB so looking for a solution using jq stream

Comment: Question clearly states the answer needs to use `--stream`.

Comment: @tilde - The original question did not specify `--stream` but did mention streaming. In the context of jq, there is a distinction between the so-called "streaming parser" (which is enabled by the --stream command-line option), and a "stream" of JSON texts.  The original question mentioned a large file, without specifying whether it was a single JSON text or a stream of JSON texts.  If the latter, then using the streaming parser would most probably be too slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][] == "userActivities"))) | with_entries(select(.value.localDate=="2018-01-19")) ' input.json
```

output:

```
{"L3ATRosRdbDgSmX75Z":{"deviceId":"60ee32c2fae8dcf0","dow":"Friday","localDate":"2018-01-19"}}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, it works. Just wanted to check if there is an option available wherein  filter can be put on multiple values of the same variable. For Example: localDate in ("2018-01-19", "2018-01-20")?

Comment: Yes. But the syntax is like this: `jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][] == "userActivities"))) | with_entries(select(.value.localDate == ("2018-01-19") or .value.localDate == ("2018-01-20")))`