# jq map_values on very large file

Tags: json, select, jq, keyvaluepair

I'm using jq to find patterns in a very large JSON file (500MB+) with the following flat object structure:

```
{
   "prop1": "large string",
   "prop2": "another large string",
   "prop3": "yet another large string",
   ...
}
```

The below query works fine and it takes less than 15sec to return results:

```
jq 'map(select(contains("PATTERN")==true))' largefile.json > res.json
```

but that returns me an array of the strings in which the pattern is found, so I lose the property names.
When I try to use map_values, so I can also get the property names, as in:

```
jq 'map_values(select(contains("PATTERN")==true))' largefile.json > res.json
```

the query takes forever.

Is there an equivalent query that is fast like map, and which can also provide me with the key:value pairs?

Comment: can you share some part of that json (if not private) with say, pastebin?

Comment: sorry, file is private, but yeah, extremely easy to recreate, just add random string values to props in sequence.

Comment: By the way, the behavior of `map_values(select(...))` varies from one version of jq to another.

Answer (score 1):

Since your JSON file is not too big for `jq` to read, a simple and efficient solution (modulo the use of jq to read the file into memory) would be to use `keys_unsorted/0` and `test/1`:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $k
| select(.[$k] | test("another"))
| [$k, .[$k]]
```

(Using `map_values` would be unnecessarily inefficient, and using `contains` is probably not a good idea unless you fully understand its complications.)

If you require the output to be a single object, you could either adapt the above, or (at the cost of the memory required for the output object):

```
. as $in
| reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ({};
    if ($in[$k] | test("another"))
    then  .[$k] = $in[$k]
    else . end)
```

#### Very Large Files

For files that are too big to read into jq normally, you could use jq's streaming parser, i.e. using the `--stream` command-line option.  Unfortunately, this is easier said than done, but an easy approach would be to use `atomize` as defined e.g. at [jq --stream filter on multiple values of same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326989/jq-stream-filter-on-multiple-values-of-same-key)

Comment: the keys_unsorted example you provided here does not yield a proper JSON object as a result. the curly brackets are missing at the top and bottom of the file.

Comment: Your question asked for the  `key:value` pairs. Maybe you should clarify your requirements, e.g. in accordance with [mcve].  In the meantime, maybe you can figure out how to tweak the jq program to achieve what you want, e.g. starting with `{($k): .[$k]}`

Answer (score -1):

Just use `with_entries/1` it allows you to effectively filter out properties of an object based on the key and/or value.

```
with_entries(select(.value | contains("PATTERN")))
```

Comment: This definitely works as I want, fast and leaving the object keys where I wanted. Thank you, @jeff